# How do I restrict SSH to one directory?

Tags: windows-7, ssh, user-accounts, remote-access, restrictions

I have a Bitvise SSH server on Win7 and I'd like to restrict access to one directory for the SSH user.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: SFTP, or command-line SSH?

Answer (score 2):

Basically SSH access gives to distant user same rights as local user. This is designed for.

If you want to limit an user SSH access to specific place. Best is to create local account for this usage. Which is allowed to see at least your specific folder.